# How can I paste newline-separated text into a bulleted list without creating new bullets?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, newlines, bullets

I have a bulleted list in an Outlook 2010 email and I am trying to paste a newline-separated list of text items into one of the bullets.  When I do this, it's bulleting each line and I don't want it to do that.  What I want it to do is treat each line as if I were pressing SHIFT+ENTER.

I've tried searching for the character control code that's generated on SHIFT+ENTER, but I have been unsuccessful.  If I could find that, I could paste the text into Notepad++ and replace CRLF with that character and then, theoretically, I'd be able to paste it into the bullet without issue.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you've found a usable answer, then please add it as an answer.

Comment: This question is actually related to Word 2010, not Outlook itself because Outlook 2007+ uses Word as a message text editor.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

1. In your list item press SHIFT+ENTER to insert a line break (soft).
2. Paste you list.
3. Select all pasted contents (auto-created list items)  *excluding the last line*.
4. Press CTRL+H (Replace dialog).
5. Type **^p** as a *Find what* and **^l** as a *Replace with*.
6. Click the *Replace All* button.